# proc macro not found

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-analyzer

My `main` function is decorated with two proc macros like this:

```rust
#[paw::main]
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main(args: Args) -> Result<()>
```

This compiles and runs as I expect it but VS code's `rust-analyzer` gives me this error on both lines of attribute macros `#[paw::main]` and `#[tokio::main]`. The error message is:

```
proc macro `main` not expanded: proc macro not found rust-analyzer (unresolved-proc-macro)
```

Comment: Do you have proc macros enabled? (setting `rust-analyzer.procMacro.attributes.enable`).

Comment: Yes, I do have proc macros enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/10894), and in particular [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/10894#issuecomment-992137143), it seems that proc macro expansion is quite dependent on the version of the Rust compiler. The suggested fix is to keep your rust-analyzer updated. Switching to the pre-release version of rust-analyzer fixed this for me on rustc 1.61, which is the latest stable in time of writing. Presumably the pre-release version of rust-analyzer is always most likely to be ABI-compatible with the latest stable version of rustc.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in the latest stable (non-pre-release version) today. #135 seems to have fixed it. The changelog also mentions proc macro errors.
https://rust-analyzer.github.io/thisweek/2022/06/27/changelog-135.html

So pre-release is no longer necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way, but this will make the error go away:

- Go to settings and find `rust-analyzer > Diagnostics: Disabled`. You can search for "rust analyzer diagnostics" to find this option.
- Press `Add Item`
- Add the item `unresolved-proc-macro` and press OK.

Source for this solution was found [here](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#unresolved-proc-macro).

Comment: It will disable the error, but not expand the proc macro.